# How to justify vampirism in general intelligence?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, robots, nanotechnology, vampires, machine-cult

In year 2278 C.E. the machines develop superior intellect on par with a 21st average human teenager's brain, both races had coexisted amicably for a long time until a robotic hacker meddled with the DNA of a certain influenza virus and unleashed it to the unsuspecting world.

This deadly virus infects only avian mammals like the vampire bat and drives its hosts into a bloodthirsty frenzy, the infected bats aggressively attack any other mammal on sight; and drain all the blood from the victim. In this future all animals are tagged, complicating matters further as the aggravated stress hormones that cause the virus infiltrate the synthetic implants; which also double as radio transmitters.

The malicious virus make use of the transmitter to send multiple digital copies of itself into the internet and then downloaded itself by any connected machine it can find. The program activates and reprograms the architecture of the core processor as well as all nanites currently residing inside the machines turning them into a terminator.

The terminators coordinate their attacks to skin humans and fill their bods with nanites, the nanites then multiply quickly by consuming the iron rich warm human blood...

A response team established a temporary quarantine and managed to trace the genetic marker to the source. Upon scrutinising the blood sampled from patient zero the authorities decipher the purpose of the code from the host DNA. The main directive is to replicate its creator's DNA as close as possible, or else run the "search & destroy" and "download/Trojan man" sub-routines...

**Question**
Could machine demonstrate vampirism syndrome such as in this scenario?

Comment: Excuse my spelling, I accidentally fell into a giant tank of fermentating substance and struggling profusely with the smartphone to send for help but typed this instead...

Comment: Usually your questions are fun. Unfortunately, not this one. This is a concatenation of pseudoscientific twaddle. Only your first paragraph doesn't contain a scientific absurdity. Anyone attempting to answer this question will be wasting their time. If you want to devise a way AI and robots could become vampires, start with something simple and build it up logically. Downvoted with regret.

Comment: @a4android: I think there's a big misunderstanding on the definition of absurdity in which case I'll be glad to clarify with pleasure.

Comment: Well, for starters, a vampire bat consumes [about 1 fl. oz.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_bat#Digestion) of blood over a 20-minute period. There's about 160 fl. oz. of blood in the human body. So, it would take 160 bats 20 minutes to drain a human's blood. Kind of implausible.

Comment: @Frostfyre: I see ur point however in the future some mammals especially rodents suffer from gigantism and now they hunt in pack! No surprise really for animal to switch modulus operandi ask Darwin.

Comment: ...So you're just going to handwave every issue that gets brought to your attention? Then the answer is clearly "Yes, because I said so." (Also, it's _modus operandi_. Modulus is a math operation.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but from what pop culture is showing us, XXI century teenagers might be lower in brainpower than their XX counterparts.

Comment: @Frostfyre: my apology I simply hope to clarify all of ur doubts and thank you for correcting my mistake.

Comment: Let's be honest, the premise is a quick example in order to prove how one *might* end up in this situation. I'm guessing the preference would be to ignore how absurd the leap from Biological Virus to (Intelligent) Computer Virus, and focus more on whether or not it would be possible for a machine/program to exist such that it used the blood of life forms for replication purposes?

Comment: IF(human_is_sick OR dna_not_optimal) THEN collect_blood_for_future_use();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Your premise is throwing the scent on this a bit - that a biological virus could convert to a computer virus simply by coming into contact with a synthetic device (or even at all) is frankly ridiculous. I'm choosing to ignore the exact scenario and focus on:

#### Is it possible that a machine would have a primary function which replicated vampiric attacks?

In which case, the answer is absolutely, but it would the most likely cause is someone programming it specifically to so. As for *why*, that's a little more difficult. Arbitrary (because it scares people) or vicarious (collecting blood on my behalf) reasons are the most plausible. Making it part of the reproduction cycle for the machine is harder as blood isn't a great fuel or building source - the average male has only [4 grams of iron in their whole body](http://www.irondisorders.org/how-much-iron-is-in-the-body/), which is a pretty crappy efficiency rate.

I think it's unlikely for this reason that a computer/program would evolve this requirement on its own, as there are far more efficient methods of obtaining natural resources.

Comment: Wonderful! This is the only possible class of answer for the rise of machine vampirism -- and by ignoring the genetically engineered virus turning into a computer virus trajectory. Well done, sir. Plus one from me.